# How do you disable fish shell's guessing autocompletion feature?

Tags: fish

In bash, if you type something like:

```
ls /etc/abc
```

and hit `<tab>`, it will beep, and do nothing, basically letting you know that it couldn't figure out how to complete it. In the case of that specific command, a file starting with `/etc/abc` didn't exist.

In fish, it will use some sophisticated algorithm to figure out what it thinks you may have meant, and can change what you typed completely, possible changing your `ls /etc/abc` to `ls /etc/fstab`, because at some point in the past, you may have typed `ls /etc/fstab`.

I'm sure it's not that arbitrary, but the fact is, it removed my `/etc/abc` arg, and replaced it with what it thought I meant. Sometimes, I made one mistake in one character, and instead of going back and fixing my mistake like I would in bash, hitting `<tab>` replaced the entire thing I wrote, forcing me to rewrite the entire arg.

I can see how some people might like this feature, but for me, it's insanely annoying. Maybe I'm just used to bash.

Is there a way to have fish turns this off, so it never replaces what I wrote? If I wrote `/etc/abc`, hit `<tab>`, and it can't figure out a completion that starts with that, leave it alone. Don't replace it with its best guess.

I don't even know what the feature is called. Does it even have a name, or is it just a nameless part of the autocompletion of fish?

Update:

A real example I just ran into.

I have a file in the current directory named `lib.py`. I type `git difftool li` and hit `<tab>`. It replaces what I wrote with `git difftool templates/nxt_connect/dish_controls.html`, immediately making me want to stab somebody as I have to delete the super long string it helpfully filled in for me, and try again. What's worse is that I assume I typed something in wrong, so I'll try exactly the same thing, and end up with exactly the same result, only to realize fish doesn't have a completion file built-in for `git difftool`, which is why it doesn't even check my current directory for files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> and can change what you typed completely, possible changing your ls /etc/abc to ls /etc/fstab,

Fish won't change `/etc/abc` to `/etc/fstab`

What it *will* do is fuzzy-match your command, so e.g. `/etc/ft` will match `/etc/fstab`, but that's only because both "f" and "t" are in "fstab" in that order, and only if it was the only possible match.

This won't happen with `/etc/abc`, because that doesn't match `/etc/fstab`.

> because at some point in the past, you may have typed ls /etc/fstab.

It does not take history into account in this case. It really only uses history for the autosuggestion - the greyed-out continuation of what you typed, but that only does prefix matching.

> Is there a way to have fish turns this off, so it never replaces what I wrote?

Fish provides no option to change this behavior.

The next fish release (version 3.2) will offer an "undo" function (bound to ctrl+z by default) so you can undo any match by pressing that.

> is it just a nameless part of the autocompletion of fish?

fuzzy matching.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This seems to also explain my real-world example I just added. I hope someone adds a way to disable this. For now, I guess I'll have to use the undo feature. Thanks

Comment: I can practically guarantee that an option to disable it will not be added. That's not the fish way. What I *can* do (and have just committed) is this: If you press escape right after the completion was inserted, it will undo it. Coming in fish 3.2.0.